# Vue-loader giving me an unexpected token error

Tags: webpack, vue.js

When I run the `webpack` command I get a strange error in the vue-loader library

```
ERROR in ...\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\parser.js:25
      output.styles.forEach(style => {
                                  ^^
Unexpected token =>
 @ ./wwwroot/app/app.ts 3:10-30
```

My webpack config looks like this:

```
module.exports = [
{
    entry: { app: "./wwwroot/app/app.ts" },
    output: { filename: "./wwwroot/app/app.js" },

    // resolve TypeScript and Vue file
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".ts", ".vue", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.vue$/, loader: "vue" },
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "vue-ts" }
        ]
    },
    vue: {
        // instruct vue-loader to load TypeScript
        loaders: { js: "vue-ts-loader" },
        // make TS' generated code cooperate with vue-loader
        esModule: true
    }
}];
```

I don't really see what's wrong with this file. Nor do I really understand why I'm getting that error. I tried removing all node_modules and reinstalling them but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need [babel](https://babeljs.io/) [loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) as well for your js:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue'
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    include: projectRoot,
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates your node.js, which you run your command with, don't recognize the arrow function syntax (which is implemented in recent versions of node and browsers). You should update your node.js.